# copy and paste entire row from one to another sheet issue

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy entire row from today Sheet to last available row of main Sheet if today Sheet B2:B cell value = "Update". However, I come up with copy area and paste area are not the same size issue. I've tried many ways but cannot get it solved. Can anyone help? Thanks in advanced.

```
Sub getnew()
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main")
Set Sheet3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("today")
lastrow = Sheet3.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim erow As Long
For i = 2 To lastrow
    erow = Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Update" Then
    Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B" & erow)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question could you clarify your question.

Which row want you to copy from sheet today, to the last unused row sheet main? 

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to copy the entire row of a worksheet, but you are pasting that row in another sheet, starting at column B. They aren't the same size, because an entire row contains 16,384 columns, but a row starting at column B only has 16,383 columns.

You have a few options to resolve this:

You could paste the entire row onto the other sheet at column A, like so:

```
Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A" & erow)
```

Or you could copy only the number of columns which you care about, instead of trying to copy the entire row, like so [I don't know what it is you're trying to copy, so you will need to figure out how exactly you want to size it. I have assumed that 10 columns is sufficient]:

```
Sheet3.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i,11)).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B" & erow)
```